# Cordova CodePush Migration - new plugin?

Tags: cordova, code-push, visual-studio-app-center

We're using [CodePush](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) with Cordova.  This service is moving to Microsoft's App Center.  The main code push site notes that there will be a new "App Center CodePush SDK Launch" in late February 2018.  I haven't seen this launch for Cordova.

It looks to me like the [existing cordova plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push) for CodePush is integrated fairly well in the App Center docs.  Is there going to be a new Cordova plugin for this AppCenter move, or will the existing plugin be usable long-term?  I know the CLI will be changing, but I'm more concerned with the app integration using the Cordova plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing CodePush SDK's will continue to accept update checks as long as they are in use. We are looking to phase out the old CodePush SDK's and CLI in favor of a new CodePush module included in our App Center SDK's and the 
already supported App Center CLI. It's our recommendation you make the switch to the new CLI, but not required at the moment.

In the future we'll release the new SDK's, wait for update checks from old SDK's to cease and then deprecate the old service in favor of our new backend that all users are currently already on. We've been doing a lot of work behind the scenes in order to make sure the transition is comfortable and smooth for all users.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't mind updating to the new CLI.  The cordova SDK was my main question.  I don't see a CodePush module in your App Center cordova plugin.  I only see the existing codepush plugin.  So for Cordova CodePush, I'm not sure what the SDK upgrade path (or timeline) looks like.  The migration plan said late February for the new SDK?

Comment: The migration plan timeline is no longer accurate, we've removed it from the website. We'll send updated messaging when possible. In the meantime, you're free to use the old SDK with no interruptions.